# Error while sending conformation emails when user sign up and try reset passwords

Tags: .net, email, azure

I have a website which was built on .NET MVC Framework. (http://www.dial4jobz.in/). everything was working fine until morning but suddenly its stop sending confirmation emails and I have no idea what's going on.  what is the main cause that is stopping to send emails? I believe the code is fine because it was working for a long time. BTW it is hosted on azure and I'm using Business mail service from Net4.in

Btw the signup process is working fine no error at all only problem is I'm not getting emails.

Comment: Have you tried to check whether you could send the email successfully, or what exception do you retrieve? Since it could work before, I assumed that there be something wrong with your mail account or configuration settings, you could try to contract with the support team from Net4.in.

Comment: here is an issue now others emails working like newsletter and others but only those came from sign up and reset password is not working. the process went smoothly it says check your email to activate your account but i'm not getting an email.